# Segregation of a finance interview based on topic discussed

Tags: nlp, data-cleaning, text-classification, semantic-segmentation, llm

I have a video interview of 5 people, which i have transcribed to text (example corpus given below). Considering the fact that we know SPEAKER_00 is the interviewer and rest are guests. I want to know the **start time** details when the interviewer has asked one question and what was the **end time** when all the other guests have finished replying to that question. The interviewer can counter question on the same topic which should be between the start time and end time of our output.

Basically help me to make multiple text file from single text croupous based on the number of questions asked by the interviewer.

```
[ 00:00:01.290 -- 00:00:01.763 ] SPEAKER_00: No.

[ 00:00:01.290 -- 00:00:20.595 ] SPEAKER_01: The framework that we work with in that if there is a surplus government land, that it is put to the market for disposal. So I suppose there was that little bit of conflict, perceived conflict with what we do and the policy that exists.

[ 00:00:09.576 -- 00:00:10.724 ] SPEAKER_00: market.

[ 00:00:20.595 -- 00:00:35.682 ] SPEAKER_02: So it's probably quite variable, I guess, depending on the politics of the day. You mentioned that there's a framework you're working with in there. Would you say you're more guarded by that framework or the politics of the day when you're making those decisions? It is the framework. Yeah.

[ 00:00:33.775 -- 00:00:47.190 ] SPEAKER_03: It is the framework. So the Government Land Transaction Guidelines dictate that we are selling government land. Or surplus government land, I should say. So that's what we work within.
```